# Integrating Google Maps JavaScript API V3 into and android project

Tags: javascript, android, eclipse, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Am currently asked to work on a project where I need to show the elevation of current place. By googling I came acrosee Google Maps JavaScript API V3 which have Elevation Service and have a sample code over [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/elevation-simple). But the code is in Javascript. So now am wondering how to move into java coding using this sample code. Have anyone worked with Google Maps JavaScript API V3 because am not sure how to integrate the javascript into an eclipse project.

EDIT 1:

Is it like I should change my IDE to PhoneGap..? I have heard that through PhoneGap you can code in HTML/Javascript and create project for Android and iOS.

I just checked with PhoneGap and couldn't find support for Elevation Service.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may directly use [Google Elevation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/) in Java. Make a request, parse json and you are done.